# Getting a count per hour for the past week

Tags: python, django

I have a model of Photos taken. I am building a heatmap with Javascript of when photos were taken of the last7 days. I am showing it per hour.

My Photo Model has a timestamp DateTime field. How would I make a list like this showing total photos per hour per day for the past week?

The javascript expects an array like this:

```
const heatmapDataSource = [
  [0, 0, 3],
  [6, 23, 3],
  ....
];
```

> heatmapDataSource[0][0] is the day of the week (Today (Tuesday) 0,
>   last week Wednesday (6) - Today is always 0
>
> heatmapDataSource[0][1] is hour (0 == 24:00 and 23 == 23:00 etc)
>
> heatmapDataSource[0][2] is the count value for that hour

Hope this makes sense!

So far I have put this together as a start to get counting:

```
    Photo.objects.annotate(
    hour=Trunc('timestamp', 'hour', output_field=DateTimeField())
).values('timestamp__hour', 'timestamp__day').annotate(photos=Count('id'))
```

Outputs:

```
<QuerySet [{'timestamp__hour': 10, 'timestamp__day': 10, 'photos': 8}, {'timestamp__hour': 12, 'timestamp__day': 13, 'photos': 1}]>
```

The Photo Model:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    camera = models.ForeignKey(Camera, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    image = models.ImageField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

**UDPATE**

This is what I have sofar that is almost there..

```
import datetime as DT
today = DT.date.today()
week_ago = today - DT.timedelta(days=7)
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractWeekDay


Photo.objects.filter(timestamp__gte=week_ago).annotate(weekday=ExtractWeekDay('timestamp')).annotate(hour=Trunc('timestamp', 'hour', output_field=DateTimeField())).values('timestamp__hour', 'weekday').annotate(photos=Count('id'))
```

Comment: Can you share the code you wrote that doesn't solve the problem for you?

Comment: You should look into ``queryset.annotate(hour=Trunc('datefield', 'hour'))`` and ``regroup`` to render it in your template. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup

Comment: Thanks, let me do this!

Comment: Please share your models.

Comment: I think I have almost answered my self. I just need to be smart with the days of week to make today 0..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we need to make some fixes to the query itself: the `__day` will have a range of 1-31, which is probably not what we want. We want the week day, so:

```
from django.db.models import Count
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractHour, ExtractWeekDay

qs = Photo.objects.annotate(
    hour=ExtractHour('timestamp'),
    day=ExtractWeekDay('timestamp')
).values('hour', 'day').annotate(
    photos=Count('id')
).order_by('hour', 'day')
```

Next we will need to do some post processing:

```
from datetime import date
dow = date.today().isoweekday() + 1

result = [
    [(row['day'] - dow) % 7, row['hour'], row['photos']]
    for row in qs
]
```

This will result in an *n×3*-list, that can then, for example, be transmitted through JSON.

Comment: How would hack it so that today is alwasy 0 (as in weekday), and then going back its 1 2 3 4 etc ?

Comment: such that "tomorrow" is 6?

Comment: Well, no, it would go backwards. yesterday would be 1

Comment: Yes, but say something is 8 days away, should it be `1`, or `8`?

Comment: Oh, no it will always display one week - so from today to 6 days back (tuesday back to wednesday). I filter it by date for the last week. See my udpate I made earlier in the question at the bottom

Comment: Then you can replace `row['day'] - dow` with `dow - row['day']` (so the subtraction in "reverse").

Comment: Thanks! that's perfect!